# tag img position on resize window or rotate mobile device

Tags: html, css

If window is maximised or the phone is in portrait position, the position of magnifying glass is in your place (it's ok).

When I resize the window or when I rotate the mobile phone, then position of magnifying glass move.

I tried to put units in px, em, vw, display inline, flex, block or inline-block etc, position relative etc but the same result.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

PS. Please excuse my English.

HTML:

```
...
<div id="input_search">
  <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" maxlenght="50" value="" placeholder="Search..."></input>
  </form>
  <img id="lupa" src="img/lupa.png">
  <img id="back" src="img/back.png">
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
#input_search input {
   background-color: #ffa366;
   color: black;
   padding: 15px 0px;
   float: left;
   border: 0px;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 1% 0px 1% 0px;
   width: 100%;}

.indent1 {
   text-indent: 17px;
}

.indent2 {
   text-indent: 57px;
}

#lupa {
   float: right;
   height:24px;
   margin-top: -11%;
   margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the image positioned inside the input? If so, an alternative option is to use the `background-image` property.

See snippet below.

*also, I think `<input>` does not need a closing tag in HTML5

```css
#input_search input {
  background-color: #ffa366;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 1% 0px 1% 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#search {
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/30x30');
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 7px bottom 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_search">
  <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" maxlenght="50" value="" placeholder="Search...">
  </form>
</div>
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/VPpQVL?editors=1100)